# Google Cloud Platform AI Notebook - how to ensure GPU is being used?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, scikit-learn, gpu, random-forest

I am using Jupyter on GCP (set up the easy way via the AI Platform) to train a `MondrianForestRegressor` from `scikit-garden`. My dataset is about 450000 x 300 and training using the machine as-is, even utilising parallelism `n_jobs=-1` (32 CPUs, 208GB RAM) is far slower than I would like.

I attached a GPU (2x NVIDIA Tesla T4), restarted the instance and tried again. Training speed seems unaffected by this change.

- Is there something I need to do when training the model in Jupyter to make sure that the GPUs are actually being used?
- Are GPUs even useful for tree-based methods? There is literature which would suggest that they are (https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-88693-8_44), but I don't fully understand the intricacies of what makes a GPU more suitable for different types of algorithms beyond the fact that they deal well with giant matrix calculations e.g. for deep learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a Notebook it allocates a GCE VM instance and a GPU, to monitor the GPU you should [install](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/monitor-gpus#setup-script) the GPU metrics reporting agent on each VM instance that has a GPU attached, this will collect GPU data and sends it to [StackDriver Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/monitor-gpus#review-metrics)

Additionally, there are two ways to [make use of the GPUs](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/using-gpus#assigning_ops_to_gpus):

- High-level Estimator API: No code changes are necessary as long as
  your ClusterSpec is configured properly. If a cluster is a mixture of
  CPUs and GPUs, map the ps job name to the CPUs and the worker job
  name to the GPUs.
- Core
  TensorFlow API: You must assign ops to run on GPU-enabled
  machines. This process is the same as using GPUs with TensorFlow
  locally. You can use tf.train.replica_device_setter to assign ops to
  devices.

Also, here is a [lecture](https://medium.com/@shachishah.ce/do-we-really-need-gpu-for-deep-learning-47042c02efe2) about when to use GPU instead of CPU and here you can read a [lecture](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221304947_Implementing_Decision_Trees_and_Forests_on_a_GPU) about the performance when using GPU over Tree training